# Can we Link sql windows server with oracle unix server?

Tags: linked-server, distributed-transactions

while inserting data through linked server it is happening but when i  execute the stored procedure in getting error like

OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "server ip" returned message "New transaction cannot enlist in the specified transaction coordinator. ".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ORSmainscSpProcssHdrSav, Line 543
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "server ip" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

sql server-windows server 2008 R2  64bit
oracle linked server->unix server
i had checked the MSDTC connection in sql server and everything is fine. can anyone help? thanks in advance.

Comment: What credentials are you using? Can you select data from oracle via the linked server? Does the login have sufficient privileges in Oracle?

Comment: Can you clarify: you can insert through the linked server with TSQL but not with a stored procedure?